# Графики chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

У меня вопрос на понимание библиотеки chart.js.
Есть пример постороения графиков https://jsfiddle.net/red_stapler/u5aanta8/1/

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
             "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 0, 56, 55, 40],
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(95,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(95,75,75,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,75,75,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [55, 49, 100, 10, 65, 13, 100],
        }
    ]
};

function adddata(){
  myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(65)
  //myLineChart.data.labels[7] = "Newly Added";
  myLineChart.data.labels.push("Newly Added")
  myLineChart.update();
}

var option = {
    showLines: true
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
    data:data,
  options:option
});
```

В примере массив labels забит статически и дальше в свойстве datasets заполняется свойство data. Как я понимаю на оси Х располагаются лейблы, а точки проставляются согласно данным data. То есть грубо говоря labels[0] будет соответствовать значение data[0].
Но что делать, если я получаю данные динамически? например я получаю данные с бекенда в виде массива объектов вида:

```
{
      name: "Sam Dow"
      date: "2019-02-12T13:57:41.381Z"
      summ: 80
    }
```

Я заполню массив labels датами, а как мне знать какой дате соответствует какая сумма? Беда начинается, когда я хочу динамически сформировать два графика, как в примере выше.
Грубо говоря какая привязка данных из  datasets.data к labels?

Answer (score 1):

Если данные приходят в виде массива объектов, то соответствие между датами и суммой как раз и определяются этими объектами. Из входного массива данных можно сделать два отдельных массива с датами и суммами, и передавать даты в качестве labels и соответствующие суммы в качестве datasets.data

```js
var inputData=[
  {
   name: "Sam Dow",
   date: "2019-02-10T13:57:41.381Z",
   summ: 80,
  },
  {
   name: "Sam Dow",
   date: "2019-02-11T13:57:41.381Z",
   summ: 40,
  },
  {
   name: "Sam Dow",
   date: "2019-02-12T13:57:41.381Z",
   summ: 50,
  },
  {
   name: "Sam Dow",
   date: "2019-02-13T13:57:41.381Z",
   summ: 70,
  },
  {
   name: "Sam Dow",
   date: "2019-02-14T13:57:41.381Z",
   summ: 80,
  }];
 var dates=[];
 var summs=[];
 inputData.forEach(function(item){
  dates.push(item.date);
  summs.push(item.summ);
 });
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
 var data = {
  labels: dates,
  datasets: [
  {
   label: "My First dataset",
   data: summs,
  }
  ]
 };
 var option = {
  showLines: true
 };
 var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
  data:data,
  options:option
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```